# Why does the React tutorial recommend that child Component states be stored in the parent Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

According to the React tutorial at https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html:

> When you want to aggregate data from multiple children or to have two
>   child components communicate with each other, move the state upwards
>   so that it lives in the parent component. The parent can then pass the
>   state back down to the children via props, so that the child
>   components are always in sync with each other and with the parent.

This seems to contradict good OOP practices where each object maintains it own state.

Answer (score 1):

> When you want to aggregate data from multiple children or to have two
>   child components communicate with each other, move the state upwards
>   so that it lives in the parent component. The parent can then pass the
>   state back down to the children via props, so that the child
>   components are always in sync with each other and with the parent.

Consider a case where a Parent has two children, with a structure as follows

```
<Parent>
    <Child1/>
    <Child2/>
</Parent>
```

Now `Child1` just has the `input` component, and `Child2` displays what was entered in the input say

In this case if you keep the value of the input in Child1, you cannot access it from the Parent as state is local to a component and is a private property . So it makes sense to keep the property in parent and then pass it down to child as props so that both children can use it

A sample snippet

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             inputVal: ''
        }
   }
   handleChange = (val) => {
        this.setState({inputVal: val});
   }
   render() {
        return (
             <div>
                  <Child1 handleChange={this.handleChange} inpVal={this.state.inputVal}/>
                  <Child2 value={this.state.inputVal}/>
             </div>
        )
   }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
   
   render() {
        return (
             <div>
                  <input type="text" value={this.props.inpVal} onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e.target.value)} />
             </div>
        )
   }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
   
   render() {
        return (
             <div>
                  {this.props.value}
             </div>
        )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Comment: couldn't the parent have access to its children and then access and then use a getter method?  Maybe that's just not the idiomatic way of doing this in React.

Comment: The parent can have access to the children component and get the value from Child and then it has to pass the newly found value to another child which which would be much more complex then the above method