# Is it possible to access the state of a child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working in a project to to replace a large Silverlight application with a web application using react (and redux). There's multiple tabs and subtabs that the user can jump between.

We are using redux to save tab/subtab-state. The current solution uses cloneElement to inject previous state and a function (onSaveState) that all components needs to call in order to save state.

**Is there a way to avoid having the save/load boilerplate code in all pages on the tabs+subtabs, for example by getting the state of a child component?**

An ugly solution is to save the entire component (including the state) but this introduce a lot of overhead + having the react virtual DOM handle something that is not actually rendered may lead to several other problems.

*Note: We are not allowed to change the overall UX.*

**Update:**  What we want to accomplish is to make save and load of state as simple as possible when the user jump between open tabs. A user can open several tabs of the same type. Most tabs have undo-functionality. It's a large application with 150+ views (not counting all smaller dialogs). To make the save/load of state from the redux store as seamless as possible it would have been nice to inspect the state(readonly) of a component (from a parent) just to save it. We have an ok solution today as I mentioned where we get the previousState as a prop and we call onSaveState on componentWillUnmount with the current state. I don't need an explanation of how redux works, I'm simply interested if it's possible to inspect the state of component from the outside (for example from a parent component) in a way that is not to hacky?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611905/why-does-the-react-tutorial-recommend-that-child-component-states-be-stored-in-t/44611941#44611941

Comment: Why is `cloneElement` involved in saving state? Are we talking about redux state here?

Comment: As I write cloneElement is used to inject a method (onSaveState) and the previous state to avoid connecting all pages to the store, hence handling the redux store actions in one place instead. To answer your second question, yes we are talking about redux (as I wrote).

Answer (score 0):

If you have complicated save/load code, don't put it all in the parent component and inject it into the children. Move it into shared files that the children can consume on their own.

Put loading code in a **reducer** file. Put saving code in an **action** file. Then let the tab components each `require` the new files so they can `connect` to the reducer and `dispatch` the action.

See [Redux Basics](https://redux.js.org/basics) for a thorough example.

Comment: It is not complicated code, it is one call (action) to save state and load is just access to the store, but still the developers need to remember this in all components.We call an action to save and the reducer stores it. The current solution is clean in that the components  only need to check if this.props.previousState exists and then on compnentWillUnmount call onSaveState(this.state).

Comment: Oops, loading code does _not_ go in a reducer; I was thinking of [Fluxible](http://fluxible.io/addons/createReducerStore.html). Loading code can be moved to stores as getter functions. Connecting to stores and dispatching actions shouldn't be so verbose that it needs to be consolidated and injected.